# How to build rerun.sh file with args in java?

Tags: java, bash

I want to build a rerun.sh script for my java code. However my java code takes in 5 args.  I want to build a rerun that can call my java class like:

```
java ­cp myjar.jar javaClassName <arg0> <arg1> <arg2> <arg3> <arg4>
```

so when I run my rerun.sh, I only need to enter:

```
./rerun <arg0> <arg1> <arg2> <arg3> <arg4>
```

Any suggestion please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple script, with basic error checking

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 5 ]; then
    echo "usage $0: <arg1> <arg2> <arg3> <arg4> <arg5>"
    exit 1
fi

java ­-cp myjar.jar javaClassName $1 $2 $3 $4 $5
```

Comment: Assuming the java program does even the most basic argument checking this would almost certainly be better as a shell function like `rerun() { java -cp myjar.jar javaClassName "$@"; }` which would allow for the number/etc. of arguments to vary as necessary.

Comment: You should quote your variables `"$1"`, `"$2"`, etc. to prevent word splitting of arguments like `'a b'` and glob expansion of arguments like `'*'`. Better yet, use `"$@"`, which takes care of this for you.

Comment: @TomFenech As a general rule, you're probably right. However I was trying to stick to the brief of exactly five arguments being supplied. Given that I do check the number of args, I think splitting would be avoided in this case.

Comment: @dave I've added my own answer, which I hope explains what I meant a little bit better.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid word splitting and glob expansion, you need to quote the arguments in the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -eq 5 ]; then
    command "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5"
fi
```

The shell provides a way of doing this on your behalf (use it!):

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -eq 5 ]; then
    command "$@"
fi
```

To demonstrate why quoting is needed, let's define `command` as the following shell function:

```
command() { echo $#; }
```

If we call either of the two scripts above, we get the output `5`:

```
./script1 a b '*' c 'd e'
./script2 a b '*' c 'd e'
```

However, if we didn't use quotes, then `*` would expand to the all the files in the current directory (or just `*` if the directory was empty) and word splitting would mean that `d` and `e` were treated as separate arguments to the script.